# cross domain ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, cross-domain

After I read [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) article, what I understand is that in order to allow cross-domain ajax calls, I have to set the server response to be ***Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ****(public for testing purpose), and here is my server code, Google AppEngine in Python

```
self.response.headers.add_header('Access - Control - Allow - Origin:*')
self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset = 'utf-8')
self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(Jsonobject))
```

I don't know if that is correct. And my Ajax call

```
xhr.open("get", "http://example.com", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","example");
```

I always got this error. ***Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*** How do I configure this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, not `Access - Control - Allow - Origin`
2. I'm not sure that `self.response.headers.add_header(str)` is valid, maybe `self.response.headers.add_header(key, name)`?
3. `*` domain doesn't work (at least not for all browsers). You have to use exact domain, full name, with protocol. Like `http://example.com`
4. You need `Origin` header, for ajax call. I'm not sure how to configure raw `xhr`, but I guess that it's made by browser itself, and you can't modify this value. Anyway, your domain not `example`
5. Don't forget that it doesn't work for most of IEs and Opera browsers.

Answer (score 0):

May be these lines of code solve your problem.

You can do one thing for that just need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin & Access-Control-Allow-Headers in CustomeHeaders your web service web.config file.

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

If you want to allow only for specific domain , you can do that with specific value of domain instead of * value