# How to XHR a remote server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is the following code sufficient for the purposes of XHRing a remote server? The only thing changed from normal XHR code is that I put the full server URL into the URL parameter of the open method of the XHR object. I'm not sure if that's enough? It didn't work; so I'm not sure what's missing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://insertURLofRemoteServerHere.com?parameter1=true",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can't because [the browser does not allow you to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222182/cross-domain-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Javascript can only send xhrs to the server from which the javascript was loading.  It's called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  I suspect that is what is stopping you.

Answer (score 1):

You code seems correct for the most part. you're handling cross browser compatiblity etc. However, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will not allow you to receive a response from a script on a remote server.

A workaround for this would be if the remote server supports the [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response format.

Another workaround is if the server supports [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control). However, from personal experience, this is spotty. I would go with JSON-P if the server supports it.

(Side note: You could make your life so much simpler if you used a library/framework like Jquery. The above code snippet could be condensed to 3-4 lines of code, and the framework will take care of cross-browser compatibility.)