# soap in ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap

I'm trying to create a basic HTML page that connects to this web service: 
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx
After hours of tinkering with tutorials and code samples, I'm at a complete loss as to why this isn't working. (I'm getting 404 on my request, or no status at all..) This is part of an assignment to expand a demo that's already using Soap to connect to a similar web service, and the professors examples are having the same issue as well..

My code follows:

```
xmlHttpObj.open("POST", "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx", true);
xmlHttpObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlHttpObj.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityForecastByZIP");

var envelope = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \n' +
               '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
               ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
               ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
               '   <soap:Body> \n' +
               '       <GetCityForecastByZIP xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"> \n' +
               '           <ZIP>' + selectedZip + '</ZIP> \n' +
               '       </GetCityForecastByZIP> \n' +
               '   </soap:Body> \n' +
               '</soap:Envelope> ';

xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = UseResultsCallBack;
xmlHttpObj.send(envelope);
```

`xmlHttpObj` is a valid xmlHttpRequest object, and `selectedZip` is a zipcode. This is all client-side code, so perhaps there's some kind of Cross-Domain issue, but I don't believe that's the problem in this case...

Comment: Is this page hosted on `wsf.cdyne.com`? If not then you have a cross domain issue (specifically same origin policy)

Comment: As a tip: I never ever use absolute url in an ajax request. Always use relative url and let the browser set the domain name. I also check this with a sanity script. The result is that it catches junior programmers trying to make cross domain ajax requests.

Comment: It's not (and will not be) hosted anywhere, just running from my laptop. And by relative url, do you mean I should set the host in the Request Header, then make the url in the open method relative? I had something like that, and it still fixes nothing. 
If this were to be a cross domain issue, how would I fix it? Would the browser be putting the kabosh on the calls?

Comment: No, setting the host in the Request Header will not work. The page must be hosted on the same domain as the source of the ajax request otherwise it will fail same origin policy check. So yes, this is a cross domain issue. Let me put your options in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments (which includes very important information not included in your question) it looks like you are trying to do a cross domain ajax request. This is not allowed. Only pages from `wsf.cdyne.com` are allowed to make ajax requests to `wsf.cdyne.com`. Even pages form `cdyne.com` are blocked from making ajax calls to `wsf.cdyne.com` because the browser considers it a different domain.

There are two workarounds to this. The first is the modern solution: CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). This requires the `wsf.cdyne.com` website giving permission to your page/site to access their data. They can do this by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to their HTTP response. You can do nothing without this modification. With this modification you don't need to do anything special, just make a regular ajax call and the browser will negotiate it with their site. Again, I stress, this is not something you need to do. This is something the `wsf.cdyne.com` admin needs to do. So contact their administrator.

However, the CORS protocol may not help you much. This is because most browsers place severe restrictions on letting you break same-origin-policy. For example, although the W3C specification allows for a `*` origin that lets everyone make ajax requests to a site, some browsers don't support it for security reasons. Also, even though `*` may be supported, some browsers disallow CORS from being used by locally hosted files (that is, pages not hosted on a server). Some are even more strict requiring the server to have a domain name, not just an IP address.

See the following links for more info on CORS:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
2. [cross domain ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222182/cross-domain-ajax)

The second workaround is the more traditional method. What is preventing you from making the request is the web browser. Programming languages like javascript, Perl, PHP, C and Java don't have such restrictions. So the solution is obvious: don't make the request from the browser. Proxy it to your server.

Remember, the proxy script written in whatever language you choose must be hosted on the same domain as your web page. Again, that means that it doesn't work with local files. But getting a minimal web server running on your local machine shouldn't be too difficult.

The proxying doesn't even need to be on a server. YUI for example uses a Flash applet to proxy cross domain request. You can try it with Java too if I'm not mistaken. But both Flash and Java have started to close down security vulnerabilities of late so this situation may not last forever. Not to mention vendors starting to abandon both technologies.

The best bet, to me, is to simply run a web server and write a proxy script for the page you want to make the ajax request to. Be warned: do not write a generic proxy script. Spammers and bot net operators are on constant lookout for open web proxies to cover their tracks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! 
Out of curiosity, IF the `wsf.cdyne.com` server had CORS in place already, then the code I'd posted should work no problem?

Unfortunately, as this is an assignment, the "correct" answer from the professor is to enable cross-domain data access in your browser settings (and doing so makes the above code work perfectly), and using a call from your server is extra credit.

Comment: Yes, by default there is no difference between a CORS ajax call and a regular ajax call apart from the cross domain URL. The browser will auto negotiate for you in a step called preflighting. If you don't want preflighting then you need to add some headers to your ajax request.